# Generating a lists of a specific length with Haskell's QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

```
-- 3 (find k"th element of a list)
element_at xs x = xs !! x
prop_3a xs x = (x < length xs && x >= 0) ==> element_at xs (x::Int) == (xs !! x::Int)
```

When prop_3a is ran through QuickCheck, it gives up, because it won't generate long enough lists.

How can I write a generator that will generate lists with length longer than the random integer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about going the other way? First we let QuickCheck pick a list and then we constrain what indices we allow. This works, and does not throw away any test cases.

```
prop_3a (NonEmpty xs) = forAll (choose (0, length xs - 1)) $ \i ->
    element_at xs i == (xs !! i :: Int)
```

Here, I use [`forAll`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.4.1.1/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck.html#v%3aforAll) to use a specific generator for the indices, in this case using [`choose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.4.1.1/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck.html#v%3achoose) which picks an element from a specified range, and I also use [the `NonEmptyList` type](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.4.1.1/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck.html#t%3aNonEmptyList) to ensure that we don't try to index into an empty list.

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, but I will need to study the code some more to understand it.  :)

Comment: Other than googling, how can I find out what package provides NonEmpty?

Comment: @JoeVanDyk: It's [from QuickCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.4.1.1/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck.html#t:NonEmptyList).

Comment: You can also use hoogle (http://www.haskell.org/hoogle) to observe that `NonEmpty` is provided by QuickCheck.

Answer (score 12):

hammar's answer is perfectly adequate for the problem. But for the sake of answering the precise question asked, I couldn't help but investigate a bit. Let's use `forAll`.

```
prop_bang x = x >= 0 ==> forAll (listLongerThan x) $ \xs ->
  element_at xs x == xs !! x
```

So now we need a function, `listLongerThan :: Int -> Gen [Int]`. It takes a length, x, and produces a generator which will produce lists of length greater than `x`.

```
listLongerThan :: Int -> Gen [Int]
listLongerThan x = replicateM (x+1) arbitrary
```

It's rather straightforward: we simply take advantage of the Monad instance of `Gen`. If you run `quickCheck prop_bang`, you'll notice it starts taking quite a long time, because it begins testing absurdly long lists. Let's limit the length of the list, to make it go a bit faster. Also, right now `listLongerThan` only generates a list that is exactly `x+1` long; let's mix that up a bit, again utilizing the Monad instance of Gen.

```
prop_bang =
  forAll smallNumber $ \x ->
  forAll (listLongerThan x) $ \xs ->
  element_at xs x == xs !! x

smallNumber :: Gen Int
smallNumber = fmap ((`mod` 100) . abs) arbitrary

listLongerThan :: Int -> Gen [Int]
listLongerThan x = do
  y <- fmap (+1) smallNumber -- y > 0
  replicateM (x+y) arbitrary
```

You can use `sample smallNumber` or `sample (listLongerThan 3)` in ghci to make sure it is generating the correct stuff.

Comment: Instead of replicateM, I'd rather use the `vector` function

Comment: link to vector function: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.12.6.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Arbitrary.html#v:vector

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
import Test.QuickCheck

element_at      :: [a] -> Int -> a
element_at xs i = xs !! i

prop_3a      :: [Int] -> Int -> Property
prop_3a xs i = (i >= 0) ==> (length xs > i) ==> element_at xs i == xs !! i
```

However, the problem with this is that a *lot* of sample values are discarded.  You could use things like `Positive` to help with ensuring that the index is valid.

If you want to be more complex, you can use more newtype wrappers to try and generate values of sufficient length (possibly using `sized`, or generate the list and the index together: generate the list, and then generate the index based upon the length of the list).